# How to understand that required layout has already been created?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, marionette

In my app I have some pages that have a similar design and a home page with absolutely different design. So, my question is how to understand that required layout (for pages with similar design) has already been created and not re-render it. Btw, in further development it may be that I'll add some new pages that will have different design. I thought about some solutions, but they're all seems like anti-patterns to me. So, I need to organize my Marionette.Controller in right way. For now it looks like this:

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette', 'app/app', 'session'], function (Backbone, Marionette, app, session) {

'use strict';

var main = app.mainRegion;

function mainContent (view, model, options) {

    require([view, model], function (View, Model) {

        if (...) { //if main.currentView is already 'layout/main' then...

            var model = new Model(options);
            main.currentView.content.show(new View({ model: model }));

        } else {
            require(['layout/main'], function(Layout) {

                main.show(new Layout());

                var model = new Model(options);
                main.currentView.content.show(new View({ model: model }));

            })
        }
    });

}

return Marionette.Controller.extend({

    home: function () {
        if (session.getToken() === '') {

            require(['layout/home', 'login/view', 'register/view', 'login/model',
            'register/model'], function(Layout, LoginView, RegisterView, LoginModel, RegisterModel) {

                main.show(new Layout());
                main.currentView.login.show(new LoginView({ model: new LoginModel() }));
                main.currentView.register.show(new RegisterView({ model: new RegisterModel() }));

            });

        } else {
            Backbone.history.navigate('/feed', { trigger: true });
        }
    },

    feed: function () {
        mainContent('feed/view', 'feed/model', {});
    },

    profile: function(username) {
        mainContent('profile/view', 'profile/model', { username: username });
    }

});
```

});

Comment: what solutions did you thought of ?

Comment: @coding_idiot 1) Marionette documentation says "If you re-call show with the same view, by default nothing will happen because the view is already in the region. var myView = new MyView(); MyApp.mainRegion.show(myView); /* the second show call will re-show the view */ MyApp.mainRegion.show(myView);". Since i thought that region will re-render it's current view if I'm passing new instance of Layout to show(), I thought to make 'main/layout' globally. 2) Using main.currentView.content.hasView() since 'layout/home' doesn't have 'content' region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using regions, you do not need to worry about it. View re-renders only if it differs from the current in the region. Also, you can check it out by hand:

```
if (main.currentView instanceof Layout) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that different instance of the same class won't be considered as different view... Btw, checking instanceof is a really great idea, I think :) It works like a charm.